# DOTS.... What am I looking for?

Tags: cipher, pattern

Dots, dots, and more dots. Try to figure out what they represent.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dots represent:

> 3.14159…

as

> Mirror image like: [image]

and

> Draw lines as directions - R for Right, D for Down, U for UP and L for Left: [image]